# Retrieve the Outlook 365 Sent Folder with imap_open

Tags: php, imap-open

I am using an exchange server, and I am able to download the inbox with the below code:

```
$hostname = "$server/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('ERROR: ' . 
imap_last_error());
```

However, when I try to download the sent folder, I have no luck.

I have tried:

```
$hostname = "{$server/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent";
$hostname = "{$server/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent";
$hostname = "{$server/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent Messages";
```

As well as various other names for the "Sent folder." What am I missing?

If I use imap I get the below error:
ERROR: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

Comment: I believe Exchange defaults to "Sent Items" for the sent folder.

Comment: Also, you probably want IMAP and not POP3, as the latter is (usually) destructive.

Comment: Yes I have tried "Sent Items," and have mainly tested IMAP: 
$hostname = "{$server/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent Items";
This did not work.

Comment: I can successfully use this with my local Exchange server: `{$server/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=$user}Sent Items`. Note the lack of `imap` in the path and the extra user at the end.

Comment: Alex unfortunately, no such luck with that. I don't know why it is not working. So strange

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$path = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/authuser=". $mail->Username ."/user=".$mail->Username."}Sent";
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, 'Password');
```